# Is overloading operators to handle my own classes as std classes a good practice?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've been going through Deitel's C++ Fundamentals and mr. Deitel accented on overloading standard operators to provide standard functionality to custom classes and their members. What I mean is for example instead of `cout << object.memberFunction();` I can simply say `cout << object;`

This technique does allow chaining and quicker typing, but it requires operator overloading implementation and even thou I am still a newb, I fell like the code actually gets **less readable**, especially if there are many class members you have to remember which ones are operators overloaded for and so on. Without overloaded operators code is much more readable plus you save the overloading code.

So my question is whether I should take the time to learn operator overloading? I am new to C++ and answers from people with more practice and experience is welcome. Will the benefits of operator overloading outweigh the efforts to implement it and the reduced code readability?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) excellent FAQ should be a good read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm tempted to say that there isn't anything to *learn* about operator 
overloading; overloaded operators are just funny named functions.  What
you do have to learn is when overloading is appropriate, and when it is
not.  Certain idioms are more or less standard: numeric types overload
the appropriate numeric operators (`+`, etc.), smart pointers overload
the pointer ops (`*` and `->`), container types which support indexation
overload `[]`, and functional objects overload `()`.  And that's about
it for the special cases.  And while it's arguably an abuse, if you
define an iterator, you'll want it to support the standard iterator 
idiom (which means `++`, `*`, `->` and `==`/`!=`).

In addition to these, there are three operators which will be overloaded
for many different types of classes: assignment is done using `=`, and
insertion into and extraction from streams is done using `<<` and `>>`.
If you want your class to support any of these, you should use the
overload.  And comparison uses `==` and `!=` for equality, and `<`,
`<=`, `>` and `>=` for inequality. But don't overload for inequality
unless it is semantically significant.  It's better to provide an
explicit ordering function for use with `std::map` and `std::set` than
to mislead readers into thinking you've defined as semantically
significant ordering.  You might want to specialize `std::less` on your
class in this case; `<` won't work, or will have inappropriate semantics
for use as a key, but `std::less` will define an arbitrary ordering
which will.  And while it's not operator overloading, if the type is to
be used as a key in associative containers, you'll also want to provide
a function `hash_code` and an instantiation of `struct std::hash`.

In many cases, it's best to define the overload in terms of some more
global function: for example: I use `compare` (returning an `int` less
than, equal to, or greater than 0), for inequality; I'll define a public
function `compare` in the class, and then derive from something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct ComparisonOperators
{
    friend bool operator==( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.compare() < 0;
    }
    //  ...
    //  The same for the other five operators.
};
```

(My implementation is actually somewhat more complex, as it uses
metaprogramming to use `isEqual` for `==` and `!=` if the class provides
it.)

I use a similar techique for the binary arithmetic operators, defining
`+` in terms of `+=`, etc.  I also use it for IO, defining `<<` in terms
of `print` and `>>` in terms of `parse`; this is mainly useful when the
operators need to be polymorphic.

Answer (score 4):

You should of course take the time to learn operator overloading. This however doesn't mean you should or shouldn't use operator overloading. But without learning, you can't really decide. Deciding on using something you're not familiar with is difficult if not impossible. You'll always find something you have no knowledge with harder to use, even if it actually is easier.

That being said, do what you assume is best on a case-to-case basis. If in your case you find the code less readable with operator overloading, by all means, don't do it. There are however situations when it is useful. But since in general overloading operators is done for the purpose of readability, if you find it doesn't apply in your case, stay away from it.

Answer (score 1):

Operator overloading improves readability in many cases, and these are the cases when it's useful. You probably had an unlucky example your first time around; especially with the operator<<, this happens, and you have learned the first operator overloading lesson: Sometimes, an explicit method call is clearer. But sometimes it is not. For an example, consider a typical matrix multiplication in C++ (e.g. with Eigen matrices):

```
a = b * c;
```

and in Java:

```
a = b.multiplyUsingTheMatrixMultiplicationAlgorithmThatsMathYay(c);
```

Operator overloading made the code much more readable. For these cases, you should study or at least know about operator overloading, and only in these cases it should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I took the standard overloaded operators for granted and didn't account for the fact there are separate implementations for every type. So operator overloading is actually quite important in many aspects like for example when using templates, so the time saving goes much deeper than I initially realized.

Answer (score -1):

It's a normal practice using a friend external operator for this purpose, something like this

```
friend std::ostringstream & operator<<(std::ostringstream &oss, Type &type);
```

and

```
std::ostringstream & operator<<(std::ostringstream &oss, Type &type)
{
    oss << type.attr1;
    oss << type.attr2;
    oss << type.attr3;

    return oss;
}
```

so you can invoke like:

```
Type val;
...
std::cout << val << std::end;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That should be `std::ostream`, not `std::ostringstream`